# For Android's Parse push notifications where should the unsubscribe method be placed?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to get PushService.unsubscribe(this, code) to work however I keep getting the same errors. I have tried putting the functions in a different order but it doesn't seem to help. Here's my stack trace right now and here's how I have the functions laid out so far.

```
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

        Parse.initialize(this, key1, key2);

        PushService.subscribe(this, code, Receiver.class);

        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, Receiver.class);
```

Whenever I add the unsubscribe method anywhere I get the stack trace of errors.

09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Operation is invalid after previous operation.
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.PushRouter$8$1.run(PushRouter.java:235)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Operation is invalid after previous operation.
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.ParseAddUniqueOperation.apply(ParseAddUniqueOperation.java:96)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.ParseObject.performOperation(ParseObject.java:2734)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.ParseObject.addAllUnique(ParseObject.java:2850)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.ParseObject.addUnique(ParseObject.java:2835)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.PushRouter.subscribe(PushRouter.java:618)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.PushRouter$1.then(PushRouter.java:72)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.PushRouter$1.then(PushRouter.java:69)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:318)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:329)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.Task$8.then(Task.java:381)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.Task$8.then(Task.java:373)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-05 15:54:41.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1406):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)